# Microsoft Word download from web server issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, download, ms-office

I am trying to troubleshoot the following issue.  A client tried to download a word document and is getting the following error.

> Your organization's policies are preventing us from completing this action 
>   for you.  For more info, please contact your help desk.

I believe this issue is because of cross-domain javascript.  However, the file is being downloaded from a pop-up that doesn't stay on the screen long enough for me to do anything. It is an issue with IE8 / 9.

I can not find which javascript is opening the popup let alone which javascript is being run from within the popup.  I am using fiddler to try and view the http requests and that is not helping.

Is there a way for me to debug what is happening within that popup?  Is there a way to debug javascript to break on a type of condition being met?

EDIT:
I have tried working on this issue on my local environment and the same issue comes up.  The popup appears to first come from the same domain https://company.aj.com, then goes to a different domain https://apps.aj.com and the file is being downloaded from the apps domain.

Comment: Where did the client try to download the document from? From what kind  of server?

Comment: You should try Chrome's developer tools or the Firebug extension for Firefox.

Comment: IIS Server
The error message only pops up when in IE 8 or 9 and client selects "Open" not save/save as (which is the option google chrome uses)

Comment: i've seen this issue with Outlook - the fix http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310049 resolved that

Comment: I have tried that Outlook fix and the error still comes up the same.